# Customize Hasura Docker Image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, jq, aws-cli, hasura

I have a need to install awscli and jq library in Hasura Docker Image. I tried to use yum, apt-get or apk commands to install the dependencies, but none of them worked.

Docker Image: https://hub.docker.com/r/hasura/graphql-engine/

how to install these dependencies in Hasura Docker Image? Any help is appreciated.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM hasura/graphql-engine:latest

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

CMD ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -o errexit -o nounset -o pipefail

DB_HOST=${DB_HOST:-postgres}
DB_PORT=${DB_PORT:-5432}

if [ -z "${DB_NAME}" ]; then
   echo "Must provide DB_NAME environment variable. Exiting...."
   exit 1
fi

if [ -z "${DB_USER}" ]; then
   echo "Must provide DB_USER environment variable. Exiting...."
   exit 1
fi

if [ -z "${DB_PASSWORD}" ]; then
   echo "Must provide DB_PASSWORD environment variable. Exiting...."
   exit 1
fi

export HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL=postgres://${DB_USER}:${DB_PASSWORD}@${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_NAME}


/bin/graphql-engine  serve
```

**DB_PASSWORD** is encrypted with KMS, so i want to use aws cli to decrypt the password in entrypoint.sh file before setting the Environment Variable: **HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL**

Comment: Which image you are talking about - can you paste exact name/link?

Comment: @VishalBiyani Here is the link docker repository: https://hub.docker.com/r/hasura/graphql-engine/

Comment: I presume you have tried to extend this image and write your own Dockerfile. In that case, can you share your Dockerfile? @thotam

Comment: @MdHasanIbrahim added my Dockerfile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to customize Hasura Docker Image with the help of Hasura Team support.

Here is the link to github issue: https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/2729

Dockerfile:

```
FROM hasura/graphql-engine:v1.0.0-beta.4 as base

FROM python:3.7-slim-stretch

RUN apt-get -y update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libpq-dev jq \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && rm -rf /usr/share/doc/ \
    && rm -rf /usr/share/man/ \
    && rm -rf /usr/share/locale/ \
    && pip install awscli

# copy hausra binary from base container
COPY --from=base /bin/graphql-engine /bin/graphql-engine

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
CMD ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

DB_HOST=${DB_HOST:-postgres}
DB_PORT=${DB_PORT:-5432}
AWS_REGION=${AWS_REGION:-us-east-1}
DB_PASSWORD_ENCYPTED=${DB_PASSWORD_ENCYPTED:-false}

if [ -z "${DB_NAME}" ]; then
   echo "Must provide DB_NAME environment variable. Exiting...."
   exit 1
fi

if [ -z "${DB_USER}" ]; then
   echo "Must provide DB_USER environment variable. Exiting...."
   exit 1
fi

if [ -z "${DB_PASSWORD}" ]; then
   echo "Must provide DB_PASSWORD environment variable. Exiting...."
   exit 1
fi

if [ ${DB_PASSWORD_ENCYPTED} == "true" ]
then
    echo "loading KMS credentials"
    decrypted_value_base64=$( \
        aws --region ${AWS_REGION} kms decrypt \
          --ciphertext-blob fileb://<(echo "${DB_PASSWORD}" | base64 -d) \
          --query Plaintext \
          --output text
    )
    decrypted_value=$(echo $decrypted_value_base64 | base64 -d)
    export HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL=postgres://${DB_USER}:${decrypted_value}@${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_NAME}
else
    export HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL=postgres://${DB_USER}:${DB_PASSWORD}@${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_NAME}
fi

/bin/graphql-engine  serve
```

Comment: I had to use `ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/entrypoint.sh"]` it wouldn't use my `entrypoint.sh` otherwise.